# execute a test method that is inside a base class from the base class

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to execute a test method that is inside a base class from the base class itself??

I have a base class which is declared as abstract and there is one test method inside this. I want to execute this test method in base class.

While i do this.  test case shows "Not runnable"

Comment: Sample code? What test framework are you using?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Put the code that you are using in the question.

Comment: And indicate what test framework / runner you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an instance of an abstract class. You will most likely have to create an empty class that inherits from the base and call the methods from there.

The only other alternative, which to me seems like a lot more work, is to use a mocking framework that supports doing this. For instance:

http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1):

of course you can't test that and you can't have an instance an abstract class.

if you feel like you need to do that, then you should reconsider your design and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Derive a class in your test from the base class. In derived class create a method that calls base class's method. Now you can instantiate the test class, I'll do a property example (just to make you work and do the same for the method, as you haven't posted your code :) )

```
//this could be created in your unit tests proj
public class MyBaseClassExtended : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyBaseClassExtended () : base() { }

    public new object SomeProperty { get { return base.SomeProperty; }
}


 //now I can test 
 [Test]
 public void Test()
 {
     var x= new MyBaseClassExtended ();
     Assert.IsNotNull(x.SomeProperty);
```